# Python folium heatmap not changing with intensity

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I am trying to change the normalized value of the gradient in a heatmap in the code below, but when I change the coefficient value the distribution of hot/cold does not change.  It should be getting "hotter" or "colder" in spots depending on what I set that coefficient to.  It's like it's not picking up the "weight" value at all.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
def generateBaseMap(loc, zoom=11, tiles='OpenStreetMap', crs='ESPG2263'):
    return folium.Map(location=loc, 
                      control_scale=True, 
                      zoom_start=zoom,
                      tiles=tiles)
  

MAP = [34.02571149, -118.366837957] 
  
base_map = generateBaseMap(MAP)


map_values = geo_stat_list_final[['ID','SecondID','Lat','Long','MoneyTotal']]
map_values['weight']=map_values['MoneyTotal']/5000


map_values1 = map_values[['Lat','Long','weight']]

data = map_values1.values.tolist()
           
hm = plugins.HeatMap(data,gradient={0.1: 'blue', 0.3: 'lime', 0.5: 'yellow', 0.7: 'orange', 1: 'red'}, 
                min_opacity=0.05, 
                max_opacity=0.9, 
                radius=8,
                use_local_extrema=False)
base_map.add_child(hm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Folium has a critical flaw when it comes to heatmaps -- it completely disregards the "weight" or z characteristic.  I've spent an enormous amount of time troubleshooting this issue, but finally came across this from github:
https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1271
Apparently, Folium still ignores the weight of a data point even today.  The "heat" of a map, is entirely due to the proximity of data points, not the strength of a characteristic.
This is a major letdown and incredibly misleading for the unknowing person who produces heatmaps using Folium.  I am looking for a solution for my heat maps outside of Folium.

EDIT: It seems they HeatMapWithTime still works just as it should.  For whatever reason the bug that prevents the regular heat maps from working does not affect the maps with time indexes.  So if you're desperate for the zoom features in Folium, create a time index and use that with HeatMapWithTime.
Alternatively, r-beginners' solution of using Plotly will work as well.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. It was a good experience for me because I have not been able to verify the data.

Comment: did you find a solution to get correct heatmaps working with legend? Searching like hours, but i didnt find any helpful answer beside of yours. My biggest problem with HeatMapWithTime is that i need the marks on the map stay after i pass a certain timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code on my own sample data and it shows the heatmap correctly. I will reply with the sample data and code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

lat = [random.uniform(33.5, 34.5) for x in range(100)]
lon = [random.uniform(-118.5,-117.5) for x in range(100)]
geo_stat_list_final = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':lat,'Long':lon,'MoneyTotal': np.random.randint(1000,5000,100)})

geo_stat_list_final['weight'] = geo_stat_list_final['MoneyTotal'] / 5000

def generateBaseMap(loc, zoom=9, tiles='OpenStreetMap', crs='ESPG2263'):
    return folium.Map(location=loc,
                   control_scale=True, 
                   zoom_start=zoom,
                   tiles=tiles)

MAP = [34.02571149, -118.366837957] 
  
base_map = generateBaseMap(MAP)

map_values1 = geo_stat_list_final[['Lat','Long','weight']]

data = map_values1.values.tolist()
           
hm = HeatMap(data,gradient={0.1: 'blue', 0.3: 'lime', 0.5: 'yellow', 0.7: 'orange', 1: 'red'}, 
                min_opacity=0.05, 
                max_opacity=0.9, 
                radius=25,
                use_local_extrema=False)#.add_to(base_map)

#base_map
base_map.add_child(hm)

data[:5] # 5 datas from first
[[33.8480473952464, -118.14858383423282, 0.3592],
 [34.06851003550549, -117.541725793199, 0.5726],
 [33.5701211585705, -118.24992088097929, 0.41],
 [34.411085864993666, -117.79288874325837, 0.6426],
 [34.24806484620283, -117.95844340200593, 0.5752]]
```

[image]

Since you are having issues with the folium heatmap and are looking for a different approach, I will respond with an example of a plotly density heatmap as one suggestion. If you make the radius smaller in points, detail is lost. The color scale is set by the customized color in the question. The official reference can be found here for [reference](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/#stamen-terrain-base-map-no-token-needed-density-mapbox-with-plotlygraphobjects).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go

lat = [random.uniform(33.5, 34.5) for x in range(100)]
lon = [random.uniform(-118.5,-117.5) for x in range(100)]
geo_stat_list_final = pd.DataFrame({'Lat':lat,'Long':lon,'MoneyTotal': np.random.randint(1000,5000,100)})
geo_stat_list_final['weight'] = geo_stat_list_final['MoneyTotal'] / 5000

fig = go.Figure(go.Densitymapbox(lat=geo_stat_list_final.Lat, 
                                 lon=geo_stat_list_final.Long,
                                 z=geo_stat_list_final.weight,
                                 radius=40,
                                 colorscale=[[0.0, 'blue',],[0.3,'lime'],[0.5,'yellow'],[0.7,'orange'],[1.0, 'red']],# custome colorscale
                                 zmin=0.0,
                                 zmax=1.0
                                ))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_center_lon=-118.366837957,
                  mapbox_center_lat=34.02571149,
                  mapbox_zoom=8)

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The things I fixed in your code are the zoom factor and radius. If the radius is too small, it will be difficult to see the change. If my answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I have about a half mil data points so that's why my radius is small.  But if my weighted value goes through the floor, or through the roof, (by adjusting the coefficient), wouldn't that cause some adjustment in the map itself?  Or do you still think the changes would be invisible?  Is there a way the formatting of the value before it is converted to a list would affect the map's ability to read it?  That's the only other thing I could think of.

Comment: To further illustrate, when I change the 5000 in the code above to 10, it should cause the overall value of most data points to be over 1, which would be red.  But the map remains the same coloring before and after (regardless of radius, at least I thought so).  That's what has stumped me.

Comment: The reason for the small radius comes from the number of data points. My guess is that you may need to look into whether folium can handle 500,000 data points. Just to confirm, did you get the same results running my code?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately same result.  Whether the value is 5,000 or 50,000,000 it's still all red.  that shouldn't be happening, regardless of the radius.  I'm totally stumped.